# Is Python's logging.getLogger scalable with many named loggers?

Tags: python, logging

I'm using logging.getLogging() in a way which is not forbidden by the documentation but not directly referred to.

My applications process data files and network connections, sometimes in threads. In order to identify the log lines for each connection and/or data file, I do the following:

```
data_file_name = "data_file_123.xml"
logger = logging.getLogger(data_file_name)
logger.info("This is logged.")

2013-07-22 05:58:55,721 - data_file_123.xml - INFO - This is logged.
```

This works very well:

- Avoids passing a logger instance around the software.
- Ensures every
  line is marked with the appropriate source identifier without having
  to manually perform it in each logging call.

My concern is this from the documentation at http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger:

> All calls to this function with a given name return the same logger
>   instance. This means that logger instances never need to be passed
>   between different parts of an application.

How are the the logger instances destroyed? Are they destroyed? After processing a million files will there be a million named logger instances waiting in memory to be used? Am I setting myself up for a memory leak as memory fills with these old logging instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How are the the logger instances destroyed? Are they destroyed? After
>   processing a million files will there be a million named logger
>   instances waiting in memory to be used? Am I setting myself up for a
>   memory leak as memory fills with these old logging instances?

They aren't destroyed until the interpreter exits. All instances are cached since this is the behaviour that you want when logging. After processing a million files there *will* be one million logger instances alive.

As you stated yourself you are using the `logging` module for something that is not part of the aim of the module, hence it is a suboptimal solution.

There isn't a public API to get rid of cached loggers, although you can clear the cache by doing:

```
>>> root = logging.getLogger()
>>> root.manager.loggerDict.clear()
```

The `loggerDict` or `manager` attributes aren't described in the public documentation, although they aren't explicitly marked as `_private`.

Instead of having a different logger for each file processed I'd use a different logger for each thread, and insert the name of the file in the required logging messages. You can write a simple function to do the logging that avoids having to insert explicitly the filename in every call to the logger.

Comment: Thanks, that clears my suspicions up. The 'million files' part was not an exaggeration so I need to change this. Looking again at the docs there is a page on adding context. Any opinions on the LoggerAdapter? http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-loggeradapters-to-impart-contextual-information  Keeping the logging API would be nice, and this allows it without the need to construct my own layer.

Comment: @nOw2 Using a `LoggerAdapter` seems appropriate.